# SQL query to change text on export, but not in database

Tags: sql

I was wondering if there is a way to write an SQL query that would change text upon export but not in the database.

For example:

I have a query that exports a .csv file with prices and quantities for selling products online. Then I manually change a few products prices to cover online fees and then upload the file. What I would like to accomplish is having this built into the query so I can have it update automatically but I do not want the price to be changed in my database.

Is this possible?

Thanks, and let me know if you'd like additional clarification.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually modify the select without affecting the data in the database. For example, if ordering shoes adds a 15% online fee, you could do the following:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN [ProductType] = 'Shoes' THEN Price * 1.15 ELSE Price END AS OnlinePrice
FROM
    [dbo].[Product]
```

If that doesn't help, can you provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?